# configure: error: enet not found

Tags: compiling, make, makefile

I am trying to build [7kaa](https://github.com/the3dfxdude/7kaa) game on my Ubuntu machine.

To build `Makefile.am`, I ran `./configure` and the tail of the result is

```
checking for gettext... yes
checking for iconv... yes
checking for OPENAL... yes
checking for SDL... yes
checking for ENET... no
checking for enet_initialize in -lenet -lws2_32 -lwinmm... no
checking for enet_initialize in -lenet... no
configure: error: enet not found
```

I am wondering what is `enet` and how to install it? it seems `apt` does not recognize it.

Even though setting `enable_enet` to `no` at [here](https://github.com/the3dfxdude/7kaa/blob/master/configure.ac#L101) will fix this problem.

```
enable_enet=no
```

I am still curious how to have this feature and what does it do?

Comment: The README (which is reproduced on the github page you linked) provides a link to it in the `Required dependencies` section: [enet.bespin.org](http://enet.bespin.org/)

Comment: @steeldriver, Oh, this is a new dependency added to their software. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can download `enet` from here: http://enet.bespin.org/Downloads.html

Unpack the downloaded file and from inside it run:

```
./configure && make && make install
```

Comment: the website is no longer available, any other sources?

Comment: found this alternative: http://sauerbraten.org/enet/